# React: how to have a Link with buttons inside, but make buttons not fire the link onclick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code:

```
const history = useNavigate();

const navigate = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    history('/link')
}

const doSomething = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    someFunc();
}

return (
    <a href="/link" onClick={navigate}>
        <span>Some stuff</span>
        <button onClick={doSomething}></button>
    </a>
);
```

This doesn't work because the `preventDefault` does not work because of the `stopPropagation()`. Of course I could use a div to avoid the link, or just remove the href all together but I'm striving for quality code, so what's the best option? I also can't use a button instead of `a` because there would be a button inside a button.

Comment: Why do you need `.stopPropagation()`? It stopping event bubbling. Is this example  suitable for you - https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-goldstine-f8wl8e?file=/src/index.js?

Comment: putting a button inside an anchor tag doesn't seem the most elegant. But calling preventDefault in the button handler is always a good idea IMO. Never know if you might be inside a form tag

Comment: And the second question - why do you preventing default anchor link handler, if you just reproduce same behavior? I suppose, you don't need `onClick={navigate}`.